# Workspace missing linked files from working copy

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Not a Pro with Xcode, here is my problem. I have main project and Pods project. Last time it was checked in 1 year ago with older cocoapod and older Xcode.

Now I installed everything and checked in in latest Xcode with latest cocoapod. I was able to refresh pods and everything compiles and works fine. However, I do get those weird warnings. How do I clean it up and remove this from appearing?

I beleive it is related to how Pod's linking/headers used to work and how it works now. But how do I clean it up?

`file:///Users/c/Documents/DMD/Pods/BuildHeaders/GoogleProtobuf/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream_inl.h: warning: Missing file: /Users/c/Documents/DMD/Pods/BuildHeaders/GoogleProtobuf/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream_inl.h is missing from working copy`

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found it. I'm new to Xcode so I didn't realize what it really means. It's source-control related. I had those files checked in previously but not they are not needed and Xcode manages it but then complains that I don't have them locally but do have them in SVN. I had to commit those "deletions" and all is well.

Figured I won't delete question, maybe it will help another newbie

Answer (score 0):

in terminal.

```
cd yourProject/Pods
```

then

```
sudo find . -type d -name .svn | xargs rm -rf
```

remove all svn files.